# Import CSV File W/Cypher To Neo4j When Number Of Items Unknown

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've been going over neo4j documentation for import csv file to the DB, and I've a question regarding unknown number of items in the CSV line file.

For example this is trivial:

```
"1","john","1986"
..
..
"n","peter","1979"
```

How can I import a network when I don't know its size?

For example:

```
"1","master","1999"
"2","slave1","2000"
```

And a different line only contains unknown number of `slaves`:

```
"1","slave1","1999"
"2","slave2","2000"
"3","slave3","2101"
...
"n","slave","2301
```

Another permutation can be `master` with `n` `slaves` or two `masters`.

How can I dynamically import the data in the CSV if there is no definite structure to it?

Sample documentation:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html